# how to create pdf in django using pypdf

Tags: python, django, pypdf

this is my views

```
def pdf_datakar(request):
    from fpdf import FPDF
    pdf = FPDF(format='letter')
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Welcome to Python!", align="C")
    pdf.output("Somefilename.pdf")
```

I want to create pdf file using pyfpdf in django but i get this error

```
The view karyawan.views.pdf_datakar didn't return an HttpResponse object. It    returned None instead.
```

how can i resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

In your view there is no return statement so at the end add return statement.

like this

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def pdf_datakar(request):
    from fpdf import FPDF
    pdf = FPDF(format='letter')
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="Welcome to Python!", align="C")
    pdf.output("Somefilename.pdf")
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Pdf created successfully</h1>')
```

For your reference use following link

[Django Writing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/views/)

Comment: It does not return pdf file

Comment: Yeah I know but you are calling this url so it's required a return statement so that in above answer return statement give a message "Pdf created successfully "

Comment: oh yeah, but i want to create pdf file :D

Comment: Try to use this link [Outputting PDFs with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-pdf/)

Comment: This is the actual reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-pdf/